# cURL Login Doesn't Set Cookie in Browser

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, curl, session-cookies

I am sure this is a very simple 'problem' that lies entirely in my lack of knowledge.

I have been doing research and testing for a few hours now, and I can't seem to the fix I want.

**The Situation:**

I have two parts to a web application - a Wordpress front end and a CodeIgniter backend. When someone logs into Wordpress, I need it to also log them into CodeIgniter.

I already have the code in place to fire off a curl POST to the CodeIgniter login function.

The Codeigniter system uses Cookies to store the logged in state.

**The Problem:**

Although the code goes though, and if I dump the cookie it **appears** to be working in the cURL response, if I use that same browser to visit the CodeIgniter directory, the user is not logged in to the system.

```
$this->session->set_userdata($userdata);

var_dump($this->session->userdata('username'));
```

As soon as the above code runs, as part of the script that the cURL script posts to, the correct username for that user is dumped.

**New Understanding**

There is no simple way to do this with curl, due to the reasons so clearly outlined below (thank you). Now I need to find an alternative for performing this simultaneous login.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that CURL is working on the server. Unless you specifically takes measures to pass the cookie back to the user, the user's browser is NOT involved in any way/shape/form in that curl request.

As well, if the CURL script on your server DOES send back the codeigniter cookie, the cookie's origin will be the server holding the curl script. If your codeigniter code is on a different host (and especially a different domain), it WILL NOT WORK - remember that cookies are tied to the site that issued them. As far as the browser is concerned, that site is the curl script's server.

In real world terms, it's like sending someone out to the store to pick up some beer for you. You get the beer, but the store's security camera will see only the person you sent and their cash register will have that person's debit/credit card on file, not yours.

Comment: That is what I feared. That being said, is there a better solution than cURL to do the simultaneous login?

Comment: If WP and CI are both running on the same server, then you CAN extract the CI cookie from the curl response, and send that out via the regular setCookie() stuff in the script's response to the client. Since it's all on the same server, it should work. If they're on different domains/hosts, you're most likely S.O.L.

Comment: They are on the same server. There is WP in the root and CI is in a subdirectory /app. I guess I will look into this more.

Comment: @MarcB there is no reason a browser extension could not set the cookies appropriately, based on the cookiejar from curl. Now maybe they've added some "security features" to prevent that, but there's always a way ;)

Comment: @morg: an extension which allows setting cookies from arbitrary domains would be a security nightmare. "nastycriminals.ru" subverting the plugin to fiddle with your "bankofamerica.com" cookies? thanks, but that extension will never EVER get anywhere close to my computers.

Comment: @MarcB hey, I just said it's possible ;) - and I think it should be. by the way your example is wrong, in real world terms you'd be giving them your bankcard, your pin, and they'd come back with the money. As we said, it's a matter of trust.